# How to open popup form submit with Ajax when click a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table with data. Above the table I have an add button and when clicking that button a form will display. But what I want is to display that form in a popup window to submit when clicking the add button.

How can I do that?

Below I have attached my screenshot.

My table view code:

```
<html>
<style>
#customers {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
#customers td, #customers th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 3px;
}
#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}
#customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
#customers th {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
</style>
<body>
<td><input type='button' name='add' class='add_class' value='Add'/></td>
<div id="created"></div>
<?php
$doc   = $display['hits']['hits'];
$html = '<table id = "customers" >
        <tr>
           <th>Id</th>
           <th>First_name</th>
           <th>Last_name</th>
           <th>Email</th>
           <th>Phone</th>
           <th>Address</th>
           <th>Password</th>
           <th>Status</th>
           <th>Createddate</th>
           <th>Updateddate</th>
           <th>File</th>
           <th>Edit</th>
           <th>Delete</th>

         </tr>';
foreach($doc as  $key => $value)
    {
        $html = $html."<tr>
                   <td>".$value['_source']['Id']."</td>
                   <td>".$value['_source']['First_name']."</td>
                   <td>".$value['_source']['Last_name']."</td>
                   <td>".$value['_source']['Email']."</td>
                   <td>".$value['_source']['Phone']."</td>
                   <td>".$value['_source']['Address']."</td>
                   <td>".$value['_source']['Password']."</td>
                   <td>".$value['_source']['Status']."</td>
                   <td>".$value['_source']['Createddate']."</td>
                   <td>".$value['_source']['Updateddate']."</td>
                   <td>".$value['_source']['File']."</td>
                   <td><input type='button' name='Edit' id='Edit' value='Edit'/></td>
                   <td><input type='button' name='Delete' id='Delete' value='Delete'/></td>

                </tr>";


}
$html = $html."</table>";

echo $html;
?>
</body>
</html>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.add_class').click(function(){
                $("#created").toggle();
            });
         });
</script>

<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".add_class").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        url  : "Crud_controller/Add",
                        data : '',
                        dataType: "HTML",
                                  success: function(response) {
                                    var result = $(response).find("body");
                                    $("#created").html(response);
                                    }
                        }).error(function() { alert("Something went wrong"); });

                });
                });
</script>
```

My form code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Add Employee</title>
      <style>
         label
         {
         display:inline-block;
         width:100px;
         margin-bottom:10px;
         }
      </style>

   </head>
   <body>

      <h1>Add Employee</h1>
      <div id="add_div">

      <form method="post" id="add_form" action="Crud_controller/add">
         <label>ID:</label>
         <input type="text" name="Id" /><br/>
         <label>First Name:</label>
         <input type="text" name="First_name"/><br/>
         <label>Last Name:</label>
         <input type="text" name="Last_name"/><br/>
         <label>Email:</label>
         <input type="email" name="Email"/><br/>
         <label>Phone:</label>
         <input type="text" name="Phone"/><br/>
         <label>Address:</label>
         <input type="text" name="Address"/><br/>
         <label>Password:</label>
         <input type="password" name="Password"/><br/>
         <label>Status:</label>
         <input type="text" name="Status"/><br/>
         <label>CreatedDate:</label>
         <input type="text" name="Createddate"/><br/>
         <label>Updateddate:</label>
         <input type="text" name="Updateddate"/><br/><br/>
         <label>FileUpload:</label>
         <input name="File"  type="file" multiple="true"><br/><br/>  
         <input type="submit" name="submit" class="add" value="Insert"/>

</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHv2x.png)

Comment: I hope those aren't live data in the screenshot :)

Comment: yes.not live data.

Comment: can you help me benjamin

Comment: Both Del and Smit Raval made suggestion for how to add modal windows to your code. After that just replace the code you got in the success callback of your ajax call so that it loads the contents instead  of the request into the modal window instead of writing it into the #created-elemnt  then show that modal window

Comment: tq for ur response@benjamin

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a bootsrap modal in your html.

```
    <html>
    <style>
    #customers {
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #customers td, #customers th {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 3px;
    }
    #customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}
    #customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
    #customers th {
        padding-top: 3px;
        padding-bottom: 3px;
        text-align: left;
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    <td><input type='button' name='add' class='add_class' value='Add' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/></td>
    <?php
    $doc   = $display['hits']['hits'];
    $html = '<table id = "customers" >
            <tr>
               <th>Id</th>
               <th>First_name</th>
               <th>Last_name</th>
               <th>Email</th>
               <th>Phone</th>
               <th>Address</th>
               <th>Password</th>
               <th>Status</th>
               <th>Createddate</th>
               <th>Updateddate</th>
               <th>File</th>
               <th>Edit</th>
               <th>Delete</th>

             </tr>';
    foreach($doc as  $key => $value)
        {
            $html = $html."<tr>
                       <td>".$value['_source']['Id']."</td>
                       <td>".$value['_source']['First_name']."</td>
                       <td>".$value['_source']['Last_name']."</td>
                       <td>".$value['_source']['Email']."</td>
                       <td>".$value['_source']['Phone']."</td>
                       <td>".$value['_source']['Address']."</td>
                       <td>".$value['_source']['Password']."</td>
                       <td>".$value['_source']['Status']."</td>
                       <td>".$value['_source']['Createddate']."</td>
                       <td>".$value['_source']['Updateddate']."</td>
                       <td>".$value['_source']['File']."</td>
                       <td><input type='button' name='Edit' id='Edit' value='Edit'/></td>
                       <td><input type='button' name='Delete' id='Delete' value='Delete'/></td>

                    </tr>";


    }
    $html = $html."</table>";

    echo $html;
    ?>

    <!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add Employee</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="created">
        <form method="post" id="add_form" action="Crud_controller/add">
         <label>ID:</label>
         <input type="text" name="Id" /><br/>
         <label>First Name:</label>
         <input type="text" name="First_name"/><br/>
         <label>Last Name:</label>
         <input type="text" name="Last_name"/><br/>
         <label>Email:</label>
         <input type="email" name="Email"/><br/>
         <label>Phone:</label>
         <input type="text" name="Phone"/><br/>
         <label>Address:</label>
         <input type="text" name="Address"/><br/>
         <label>Password:</label>
         <input type="password" name="Password"/><br/>
         <label>Status:</label>
         <input type="text" name="Status"/><br/>
         <label>CreatedDate:</label>
         <input type="text" name="Createddate"/><br/>
         <label>Updateddate:</label>
         <input type="text" name="Updateddate"/><br/><br/>
         <label>FileUpload:</label>
         <input name="File"  type="file" multiple="true"><br/><br/>  
         <input type="submit" name="submit" class="add" value="Insert"/>
      </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
    </body>
    </html>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

Don't forget to include Bootstrap js and css in your file.No need to send AJAX request to fetch form html.

Answer (score 1):

Basically just use a modal (popup) then move your `#add_div` inside the modal and also the insert button. Then in your add button just add a event that triggers the modal with your `#add_div` below is the attached link on how to create and trigger a modal by just using plain javascript.

https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_modal.asp